# Why would alert view delegate method not get called?

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

In my interface file I said I conform to the UIAlertViewProtocol and I implemented the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: method in my implementation file, and normally whenever the alertview button is pressed (the button that makes the alert go away)that method gets called. Well, it gets called most of the time, but for one of my alert views it doesn't get called after I press the cancel button on it, what would be a reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Its because in one of my alert views for the delegate parameter i passed in nil instead of self, thats embarassing.